# How to protect OpenERP module source code for OpenERP?

Tags: module, odoo

We developed special OpenERP module with time expiration. We also don't want to give away the source code of that module. How can we protect it? Can we just install the `.pyc` file on a customer's Ubuntu server? However, in our case all `.pyc` files are deleted every time the OpenERP service restarts.

Comment: Formatting/grammar fixes; you may want to consider being a bit more specific on expanding about what you want.

Comment: Small grammar fixes.